# Access external xml file using jquery/javascript in html5 app without hosting the file

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery/java script/html 5.
I am creating an app where I will be reading an XML file from sdCard folder in mobile and parsing it;after which the data will be populated on page accordingly.

How can I access external XML file for mobile app without hosting the XML file?
I need to access it from local drive.I will have a specific path.
I need to pick the XML data through my application.

Currently I am creating the application as HTML page in Microsoft Visual Studio and trying to access the XML file which is placed in a folder in my 'D drive'.

Thanks in advance.

No help yet...can anyone suggest some ideas please????

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is this an app for Win 8? Are you creating a win 8 app using the JS SKD? How is the user supposed to access the App, over the internet or is this an installed mobile application? More information is needed!

Comment: this will be later wrapped as an apk and run on Android .Also, it will be used directly on windows i.e. web-based.Right now this is a sample app which I am creating.

Comment: JS directly cannot be used to access data from your drive on a web application. Not possible due to sand boxing of web-platform as a whole. If its an android app, then you can check phone gap on how to use resources.

Comment: I have the specification of not using phone-Gap. Can you please suggest some other approach if possible?

Comment: I am not aware of any approach that can allow js to fetch files from your computer location on the web application instance. You can probably try getting the file loaded from the server and try cache manifest to store the file offline. This way the file will work offline incase your application has no access to internet. That is the only option I can suggest.

Comment: Thanks Shouvik for the help, but that does not match the requirement.Let us see if someone can come up with other approach.